# Do all bindings require setting URLACL?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

We set up a windows app that talks to a windows service for certain operations.  It's set up and working using wsHttp but we need to add the url to the URLACL list for the service to run.  Is this going to be an issue with other bindings as well, or are we basically just using the wrong one at this point?

In the future the service might be moved from the end user's local machine to a server on their network, so maybe we should use some other binding?

Comment: What is the URLACL list?

Comment: It's how you set the namespace reservation so a service can start listening at an address:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx

Comment: So, I would think that any binding that listens at an address would need to have the reservation, right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the "next" best option is netTcpBinding, but to use that you need to start the TCP Port Sharing service:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731810.aspx

Since the whole point was to simplify installation on client machines and reduce the number of changes to their configuration I'm not sure that gives any real advantage.  I could convert to netTcpBinding for speed since it is the fastest protocol... but in this case it's fast enough to not justify more dev time.

Hate answering my own question, but hopefully this helps someone else down the line!